# Adding a Tab to facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, tabs, facebook-page

I just created a facebook page.
I also have a separate facebook APP.

How can I add a tab containing my facebook APP to the facebook page?

I've set the app to allow install on pages, and added a tab name, tab image, etc, but the app doesn't show as an application to be added on the Facebook page when people access my app

Answer (score 57):

You can use this link,
add your `app_id` and `app_namespace`,

```html
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOURAPPID&next=URLOWNEDBYOURAPP">Tab Link</a>
```

Comment: yeh that will do it, not sure you need the link in something, just paste the url in the address bar.

Comment: It's the hosted URL of your app, not the Facebook one.

Answer (score 27):

This used to be simple, using the Facebook UI. Unfortunately facebook removed this.

you can add it using
http://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&next=YOUR_URL

I put this an html and published it below. Just visit, enter your app params, hit submit, and you're done.

http://www.jibecompany.com/2012/add-a-facebook-page-tab-application-to-your-page

Comment: The link you have **does** use Facebook UI

Answer (score 9):

There are two main ways to do this, and a third which I think is out of scope because it's outside the control of the app developer

## 1) Add Page Tab dialog

For this, you send the user to the dialog and they're prompted to add your app to your page

Example usage is to link the user to a URL of this format:

```
http://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab
  ?app_id=<APP_ID>
  &redirect_uri=<A URL OWNED BY YOUR APP>
```

Any URL owned by your app works for the `redirect_uri` parameter, but in most cases you'll want to use the same value your app uses for 'Page Tab URL' or 'Secure Page Tab URL' in the app settings

For a working example, you can add the [InstaTab](https://www.facebook.com/instatabapp) app using [this dialog](https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=168188869963563&redirect_uri=https://fbapp.us/apps/instatab/)

The admin will see a dialog that looks like this:
[image: Add Page Tab Dialog prompting a user to add the 'InstaTab' app to their page]

Full documentation for the dialog is in the [Add Page Tab dialog documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/add_to_page/)

## 2) Post your app to the user's page(s) using the API directly

Using the [Page object's `/tabs` connection](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/tabs) you can add your app to a page directly.
To make the API call you'll need `manage_pages` [permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/#reference-pages) from the page admin.

Once you have that, use the [Page access token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#pagetokens) to make a POST request to `/v2.0/<PAGE ID>/tabs` with the one parameter, `app_id` with a value of the App ID of the app you want to add to the page. If the app provides a page tab, that tab will be added to the page.

A sample API call would be a HTTP POST to

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{page-id}/tabs
    ?app_id={app-id-to-add}
    &access_token={page-access-token}
```

## 3) Page settings interface on Facebook.com

The page admin can use Facebook's Page management interface to search for apps which provide page tabs in the [Apps for Pages section of the App Center](https://www.facebook.com/appcenter/category/pageapps/) - in this case you'll need a way to get users who find your app via this method to add the tab using one of the methods aboce

Answer (score 7):

## Solution !

1) Enter https://developers.facebook.com/apps/ and choose (*or create*) desired app.

2) do this from settings:
[image]

3) then enter:

```
- https://facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=APP_ID&redirect_url=https://yoursite.com
or
- http://facebook.com/add.php?api_key=APP_KEY&pages=1&page=PAGE_ID
```

Comment: how do I deploy it to my page?

Answer (score 6):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/add_to_page/

There is a URL there, just hit it, after replacing the app id and the Canvas URL for your app.
e.g.

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=123456789
&display=popup&next=http://www.myhosting/myapp/index.php
```

It will then ask you to select which of YOUR pages you would like to add the app to.

An app is an app, and a page is a page.  When people talk about Tabs, that is when you have added the App to the page, as on the old FB page layouts the apps list were tabs down the side.

Answer (score 4):

Add a Profile Tab page at the developer page (Edit Settings > Profile) http://www.facebook.com/developers/apps.php

You can add all Apps as Tab which are currently active in your session and have Tabs-Urls added.

Use the "+" icon at the Public Profile/Page to add it - if its not in the list use the search function at the bottom of the list.

If you're Tab is blank open the Tab Url directly. If its not working there fix it until it is. If it is working there the problem is within the communication of fb with your host. Check your Logfiles!

Wild guess: 
Be aware that facebook fetches this pages via POST request. I had a nasty bug because nginx 500's all post requests to static files (e.g. HTML files).

Answer (score 2):

A bit late for you, but may be for others, I found out how to add my app to a new tab:

1. You need to create a profile for the page admin! If you didn't, on the top right of Facebook page you should have a link 'Create Your Profile'. It doesn't make sense to me but ...
2. Go to this link (thanks ifaour):https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL&scope=manage_pages&response_type=token
3. Got to your http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=YOUR_APP_ID and add the app to your page

Comment: How backwards is that, oh my god. Thank you so much, step #2 was all I needed to do. I swear there used to be an easier way to do that.

Comment: why you need to create a profile first? it works fine, just use the link with your app id and app namespace.

Comment: It might be working now, I'm pretty sure it wasn't at that time, I lost hours on that. I sure tried the link with the app id a bunch of times.

Answer (score -3):

I think [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/) is what you're writing about:

1. Go to your app's page
2. Click `add to my page`
3. Choose page where you want to add a PageTab for your app

Comment: I cannot find the "Add to my Page" link. BTW, just to confirm, when i click on my "App Page", I assume u mean the "Apps" on the top menu and  the url becomes "https://developers.facebook.com/apps".

Comment: Add to my Page has been deprecated. iFrame apps no longer have fan pages.

Answer (score -4):

I'm a little confused as to what you're meaning by 'tab'. The FB formatted tabs are created using something like this:

```html
<div style="padding:10px;padding-top:0px;padding-bottom:0px;">
    <fb:tabs>
        <fb:tab-item href="index.php" title="Home"/>
        <fb:tab-item href="page2.php" title="page 2"/>
        <fb:tab-item href="page3.php" title="page 3" align="right"/>
        <fb:tab-item href="page4.php" title="page 4" align="right"/>
    </fb:tabs>
</div>
```

Again, just a stab in the dark here.

Comment: Hi Travis, thanks for the response.

When I say tab, I'm referring to profile tab.
e.g http://www.facebook.com/skittles (see they have a custom tab called "Holla")

I'm actually able to add the tab now, but am now faced with another issue.
Clicking on the tab gives blank content.

Doing a google search, people seems to be saying "don't do redirect". Any idea what that means?

Thanks,
Tee