# How to add tab application to a page with the "new auth dialog"

Tags: facebook, dialog, authentication

I created an app today, as i've done several times before. But when i wanted to add the app to a a page i couldn't find the link "view this apps profile page", which I normally use to add the app to my pages.

Anyone know how to add apps to a page, with the new "auth dialog" thing ?? I can't find a link to the apps profile page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding a Tab to facebook page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370636/adding-a-tab-to-facebook-page)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can do it in several ways:

- Using [Add Page Tab Dialog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/add_to_page/) as described in documentation:

  - With JavaScript not even leaving page where this get called `FB.ui({method: 'pagetab'});`
  - By redirecting to `https://facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=APP_ID&redirect_url=URL`
- Via link `http://facebook.com/add.php?api_key=APP_KEY&pages=1&page=PAGE_ID`
- <strike>From Application Profile page (you can easily get to it via `http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=APP_ID` or via shorthand `http://facebook.com/APP_ID` or by clicking on Application Name in the left bottom corned of every page while visiting Application Canvas) 
  (*note that newly created apps don't have an Application Profile page - as discussed on the [Developer Blog](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/611/)* )</strike>
- Using the API directly with a `manage_pages` access token - details in the [Page documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#tabs).

Comment: @thaddeusmt, this is called "Add Page Tab Dialog" and listed as an option one.

Answer (score 13):

I have found this to work the best:

```
http://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com
```

Answer (score 1):

Tried all of above. The only one that worked for me was this one:

```
https://www.facebook.com/add.php?api_key=YOUR_API_KEY&pages=1
```

Comment: Worked for me, and allowed me to select page to add app to.

Answer (score 0):

## YOU SHOULD CHOOSE "ADD PAGE TAB" in "ADD PLATFORM" DIALOG!!

1) Enter https://developers.facebook.com/apps/ and choose (*or create*) desired app.

2) do this from settings:
[image]

3) then enter:

```
- https://facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=APP_ID&redirect_url=https://yoursite.com
or
- http://facebook.com/add.php?api_key=APP_KEY&pages=1&page=PAGE_ID
```