# How do I now add my application to my page?

Tags: facebook

I have created a landing/welcome page for a new client and the process seems to have changed.  I can no longer go to the application profile to add it to the page.  I was able to locate instructions through a google search that involved the following link:

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&display=popup

I replaced "popup" with what I thought was my canvas and I replaces "YOUR_APP_ID" with my app id taken from the settings.  I get API Error Code: 100
API Error Description: Invalid parameter
Error Message: Requires valid redirect URI.

Answer (score 2):

You missing required parameter `redirect_uri` for dialog and you should not replace `display` to your canvas but use [`display mode`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/#display)

You can simply use Facebook JavaScript SDK `FB.ui` method which will add 'em for you. See [Add Page Tab Dialog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/add_to_page/) documentation.

Using just this code will do the work:

```
FB.ui({
  method: 'pagetab'
});
```

Comment: To see more ways to do this you can also read my answer for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8596217/how-to-add-tab-application-to-a-page-with-the-new-auth-dialog

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

[`http://www.facebook.com/add.php?api_key=<YOUT_APP_ID>&pages`](http://www.facebook.com/add.php?api_key=%3CYOUT_APP_ID%3E&pages)

Comment: eureka, no it doesn't work.  It just takes me to the Facebook newsfeed.  And juicy, I am confused.  What would I do with that code? I am not a coder so a lot of this is like a foreign language to me.

Comment: when i add a tab through this url they redirected to me fanpage how do i create custom redirect

Answer (score 0):

I just successfully added my app to my page, but had an interesting "gotcha".

I used [Add Page Tab Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/add_to_page/) as suggested by other people. That worked just fine, but when I navigate to the newly added tab in my page, I got an error:

```
405 - HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed.
```

It turned out that "Secure Page Tab URL:" in your app's basic settings screen that do end with "/" character. I first specified an explicit HTML page called "landing.htm" and I got the error, then I created a sub-directory called "pagetab" with its default index page, and that didn't fix. Then, I tried "pagetab/" and it worked.

I wish they supported an explicit page URL.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your app canvas page, witch could be found developers.facebook.com/apps/ when you log in. Select your app id and paste it like: facebook.com/YOURAP . It should look something like this: 282906808394888 . After that you can see i left down corner link: Add to my page. From the given list select page you want and your tab will appear in your page like you want :) Feel free to ask if you still have problems.