# No Tabs-Urls added

Tags: windows, facebook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add tab application to a page with the “new auth dialog”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8596217/how-to-add-tab-application-to-a-page-with-the-new-auth-dialog)

I just have "programmed" a new tab for my fanpage as described in the help for developers.
(https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/)

I have got a app ID, but no App Urls. I can't reached the App Page to add it to my fanpage.

Why does the app don't work? Where can I get help. It looks so easy, but I am on it for hours now.
Thanks a lot.
Wolfgang

Comment: You can find how to add tab to your page in this question http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8596217/how-to-add-tab-application-to-a-page-with-the-new-auth-dialog

Comment: Thanks for the link. I understand that my app don't have a profil page anymore, because I just have created it. I have tried the other ways and get this error:
An error occurred with WingTsun. Please try again later.

API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: redirect_uri is not owned by the application.

Answer (score 0):

From the Facebook Documentation:

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&next=YOUR_URL

YOUR_URL seems to need to be the Website Url associated with your App.

Answer (score 0):

Finally it works.

If anybody do have the same problem, here a hint:

`YOUR_URL` is the path to the app hosted on your server (e.g. `https://www.example.com/app/index.html`).