# Adding app as page tab

Tags: facebook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adding a Tab to facebook page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370636/adding-a-tab-to-facebook-page)

I have created a Facebook app and in the Page Tab options I have entered a name of the tab and one http url and one https url to a wordpress page on my server.

I did this without problem with other apps a year ago but now I cant add the new app as an tab here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMcRt.jpg

It doesn't show up.
What have I missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&next=YOUR_URL

Comment: Ah. Thanks. It's great to see Facebook working to make things easier...