# Can't add page tab to Facebook page - get no prompt to add page

Tags: facebook, facebook-page, facebook-iframe, facebook-tabs

I relate to this well known Page Tab Tutorial by FB: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs.
The third step, after filling of page tab info and adjusting of the tab width is getting a prompt to select a page, to which the newly created tab will be added. But i don't get this promt, like it's written in the tutorial and seems to be the normal case for all users.

[image: Adding page tab prompt]

After i edit tab details and press "save changes", the page reloads with "saved"-message, like on this screenshot,

[image: no add page prompt]

and i see no further given possibility to add created app to any of my pages. If i go into the administration area of any of my pages, in the tab "apps" is this newly created app not present, so i can't add it from there too. What i'm doing wrong? The solution must be simple - i go crazy:( I tried it with Firefox and Chrome, setted off all popup- and adblockers - nothing goes...
Thanks for ideas and advice!
Evgeniy

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding a Tab to facebook page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370636/adding-a-tab-to-facebook-page)

Answer (score 13):

The "manual solution" to this problem has changed. While logged into facebook, visit this link in your browser:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL
```

There are two parts of this link you must change before it will function.

**YOUR_APP_ID**: Find this in your app settings or app dashboard URL. It's a long number, 16+ digits.

**YOUR_URL**: Use the URL of the content your new tab page will call, ie "Tab Page URL" as entered in your app settings.

This newly modified URL will load a page with a dialog where you can choose which of your Facebook Pages to add the tab to.

These instructions appear [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs#adding) but they are far from clear. Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

For anybody who will look for solution:
to add a page tab to any page do it manually: edit a link
http://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=HERE-COMES-APPID-OF-YOUR-PAGE-TAB-APP&redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com
fill into the link the app id of your newly created page tab and run this link in your brwoser: you will get a site with the prompt from the first image i cited in the first post. There you will be able to select one  or, with pressing SHIFT, many pages to add your app/page tab.

Answer (score 0):

## You must choose "**PAGE TAB**" in the dialog ! ! !

see the TUTORIAL here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35287477/2377343